# Adobe Flash Builder Flex Video Player - Full screen on init

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a created a flex application with a video player. The application goes full screen. Now I am trying to make the video go on full screen on inital launch.

I have tried to google how to do this, but came up with nothing. Here is my app code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="myVid.play();"
                       applicationComplete="init()"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       xmlns:media="org.osmf.media.*">

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:VideoDisplay id="myVid" 
                        source="augusta.mp4"
                        autoPlay="true"
                        volume="0"
                        loop="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        />
    </s:VGroup>

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void  
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            } 
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the container with the newly-resized dimensions would be a first step:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)"
                       applicationComplete="init()"
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       xmlns:media="org.osmf.media.*">

    <s:VGroup id="vidContainer">
        <s:VideoDisplay id="myVid" 
                        source="augusta.mp4"
                        autoPlay="true"
                        volume="0"
                        loop="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        />
    </s:VGroup>

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[
            private function onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
            {
                vidContainer.width = this.width;
                vidContainer.height = this.height;
                myVid.play();
            }

            private function init():void  
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
            } 
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

(note that I didn't actually test this; I don't have a video file handy for testing the VideoDisplay component)